# Parsing a JSON string in C# like javascript or python do

Tags: javascript, c#, python, json, ajax

I am trying to make a program that needs to read JSON data from a give file. But the JSON files may be very complex. Here is the code i am using

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //step one: get a correct file path
    string filepath = getFilePath("Please write here the path to your file");
    //getFilePath is just a function I wrote to read user entry and automatically sanitize the string.
    while (!File.Exists(filepath)) { filepath = getFilePath("The file path appears to be wrong, please correct."); }
    //Setep 2: read the text of the file
    string fileJSONString = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
    //step 3: parse 
    object myDictionaryFromJSON = (new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(fileJSONString));
    object question1 = myDictionaryFromJSON.questions[0];
}
```

The thing is that Visual Studio gives me a lot of erros. I have tried using `Dictionary` instead of `object`, but it still doesnt work the way I need it to work. For example, this would actually work on python.

```
myDictionaryFromJSON = json.loads(JSONtext);
question1 = myDictionaryFromJSON['questions'][0];
question1text = question1["theQuestion"];
question1options = question1["options"];
question1correctAnswer = question1["correctAnswer"];
```

This is just an example. The thing is that Python and javascript can work with json perfectly, and are really good at converting JSON strings to dictionaries and objects. But C# is not working. I don't know what  to do. What could I do?

Comment: Use this json parser is more flexible https://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: I also recommend Json.NET... I already used it several times and it really works great. You even can prepare a class and then fill this class by deserializeing the JSON-string...

Comment: Json.net supports the syntax you show above.  See [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are not using Json.NET. If this the case, then you should try it.

It has the following features:

1. LINQ to JSON
2. The JsonSerializer for quickly converting your .NET objects to JSON
   and back again
3. Json.NET can optionally produce well formatted, indented JSON for
   debugging or display

Look how fast Json.NET compared to JavaScriptSerializer:https://i.stack.imgur.com/T77y2.png

Example code for load json file in C#:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\videogames.json"));

// read JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\videogames.json"))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
}
```